Interchangability of USB chargers
I have several mains powered chargers, all supplying 5 volts output via the original USB type A socket. When purchased they were typically supplied with cables with the USB type A plug at one end and all sorts of USB plugs at the other. I also have lots of rechargeable devices with power input by a variety of USB sockets.
Assuming the connectors fit comfortably, can I use any charger with any rechargeable device, using a cable to match?
I am aware that some chargers only provide a limited amount of current. If I use a charger that provides less maximum current than the device to be recharged would prefer, will I cause any damage, will the device not charge at all, or will the recharge time be longer than originally intended?

they are not chargers, they are power supplies ... the battery charger is built into the cell phone

Most devices will charge slower if connected to a power capacity source although occasionally some devices will refuse to charge at all if the capacity is too low. Basically the device can choose to do whatever it wants.

We cannot know what happens if you mix and match a device pulling more current without negotiating from a supply that cannot provide that current. A supply may shut down, restart dozens or hundreds of times per second, provide undervoltage, or overheat if more current is pulled than it is capable of supplying. They are not meant to be misused like that for sure and it is not correct usage of the devices, so they don't have to work or stay undamaged.

you can get a cheap usb meter with V+A readings to verify a device draws less than the charger's rating, which is almost always mentioned on a sticker somewhere on the charger.
